# How to get set-based solution for a difficult join

Tags: sql

I've got a Table with a list of Products.
I've got a Table with a list of Merchants.
I've got a Table with a list of Warehouses.

I've got a WarehouseMerchant Table so a a warehouse can have many merchants assigned.

I've got a WarehouseMerchantProduct Table so a merchant can have its products listed in a warehouse

I've got a Merchant Link Table which can link 2 merchants

```
MerchantLinkID      int 
MasterMerchantID    int 
LinkedMerchantID    int 
PreferenceOrder     int
```

What i need to do is pass in a product ID and get a unique list of merchants products who can sell it.

4 Rules

1. If the merchant has a linked merchant who also sells the product, then don't show the linked merchants product
2. If the merchant has a linked merchant who also sells the product, but the master merchants stock level is 0, then only show the linked merchants product
3. In the event that a merchant has stock in multiple warehouses, then there is a preference order in the warehouseMerchant Table to select which one to use
4. There should only be one product per merchant after this has all ran

I've been racking my brains trying to figure out a solution.  I was going down the route of cursors, but it was getting a bit unwieldy.  Then i was given the 4 rules as a requirement which sent me back to the drawing board.

If anyone can think of a quick and easy(ish) set-based solution for this then I'd love to hear it.

Here is the script to create the tables and relationships

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MW_Merchant](
    [MerchantID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MerchantName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [MerchantCode] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Merchant] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MerchantID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [ucMerchantCode] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [MerchantCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_Warehouse]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MW_Warehouse](
    [WarehouseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Warehouse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WarehouseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct](
    [WarehouseMerchantProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MerchantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [StockLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MW_WarehouseProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WarehouseMerchantProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant](
    [WarehouseMerchantID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MerchantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PreferenceOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MW_WarehouseMerchant] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WarehouseMerchantID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink](
    [MerchantLinkID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MasterMerchantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LinkedMerchantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PreferenceOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MW_MerchantLink] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MerchantLinkID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_MW_WarehouseMerchant_PreferenceOrder]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MW_WarehouseMerchant_PreferenceOrder]  DEFAULT ((10)) FOR [PreferenceOrder]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct_PriorityOrder]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct_PriorityOrder]  DEFAULT ((10)) FOR [PriorityOrder]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant] FOREIGN KEY([MasterMerchantID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant1]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant1] FOREIGN KEY([LinkedMerchantID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_MerchantLink_MW_Merchant1]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Merchant]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Merchant] FOREIGN KEY([MerchantID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Merchant]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Warehouse]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Warehouse] FOREIGN KEY([WarehouseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ([WarehouseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchant_MW_Warehouse]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct_MW_Merchant]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct_MW_Merchant] FOREIGN KEY([MerchantID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct_MW_Merchant]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_MW_WarehouseProduct_MW_Warehouse]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:17:39 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseProduct_MW_Warehouse] FOREIGN KEY([WarehouseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ([WarehouseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MW_WarehouseProduct_MW_Warehouse]
GO
```

And some test data

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_Merchant]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:41:50 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ON
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID], [MerchantName], [MerchantCode], [Active]) VALUES (24, N'Merchant 1', N'MERCH1    ', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID], [MerchantName], [MerchantCode], [Active]) VALUES (27, N'Merchant 2', N'MERCH2    ', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Merchant] ([MerchantID], [MerchantName], [MerchantCode], [Active]) VALUES (28, N'Merchant 3', N'MERCH3    ', 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_Merchant] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_Warehouse]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:41:50 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ON
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ([WarehouseID], [WarehouseName], [WarehouseCode], [Active]) VALUES (12, N'Warehouse 1', N'WARE1', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ([WarehouseID], [WarehouseName], [WarehouseCode], [Active]) VALUES (13, N'Warehouse 2', N'WARE2', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] ([WarehouseID], [WarehouseName], [WarehouseCode], [Active]) VALUES (14, N'Warehouse 3', N'WARE3', 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_Warehouse] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:41:50 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] ON
INSERT [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] ([WarehouseMerchantProductID], [WarehouseID], [MerchantID], [ProductCode], [StockLevel], [Active], [PriorityOrder]) VALUES (93, 13, 24, N'TESTPRODUCT', 20, 1, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] ([WarehouseMerchantProductID], [WarehouseID], [MerchantID], [ProductCode], [StockLevel], [Active], [PriorityOrder]) VALUES (96, 14, 24, N'TESTPRODUCT', 20, 1, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] ([WarehouseMerchantProductID], [WarehouseID], [MerchantID], [ProductCode], [StockLevel], [Active], [PriorityOrder]) VALUES (97, 14, 27, N'TESTPRODUCT', 10, 1, 10)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_WarehouseMerchantProduct] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink]    Script Date: 04/30/2013 09:41:50 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] ON
INSERT [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] ([MerchantLinkID], [MasterMerchantID], [LinkedMerchantID], [PreferenceOrder]) VALUES (22, 24, 27, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] ([MerchantLinkID], [MasterMerchantID], [LinkedMerchantID], [PreferenceOrder]) VALUES (23, 24, 28, 2)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MW_MerchantLink] OFF
```

In the example data, my returned row should be the WarehouseMerchantProductID 93
93,96 and 97 all have stock, however

93 and 96 belong to the same merchant and should be selected based on PreferenceOrder in the WarehouseMerchant Table

Merchant 27 is linked to 24 so shouldnt appear (unless 24 goes out of stock)

Comment: This is a new and interesting use of the number 2 that I've not previously encountered. (You say 2 rules twice, and then have 4 bullet points?)

Comment: oops...sorry...started off as 2, then i remembered important information (3 & 4) and forgot to update it.

Comment: Can you post your create table statements along with some sample data to get us started? Most of us are lazy and can't be bothered to setup 6 tables just so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Some sample data (that exercises all of the rules in both directions) and expected results would really help here. If you could create the sample data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it would help enormously.

Comment: What do you mean by "sells the product"? I presume there's a foreign key from Products to Merchants, but without the DDL we can't be sure.

Comment: OK gimme a sec...first time posting here so not used it before

Comment: I can't get SQLFiddle to work, repeatedly get "Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.: " when i write a simple table creation query

Comment: I added the SQL script to create the tables if that helps?

Comment: It is reasonably simple: requirements {1,2} : use a `not exists(... other merchant)` subquery. {3,4}: use a `window ... row_number()=1`. But since the question is in nonstandard [microsoft].[syntax], I will not elaborate.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know the questions had to be in a certain format.  Bearing in mind that the warehouseMerchantProduct table is the main returned row and the MerchantLink table is used to "filter" out linked merchants (or replace depending on stock level), I'm struggling to see how your solution would work

Comment: You are on the right track: start from the top: `warehouseMerchantProduct`, and add joins / subqueries to restrict the results to the ones you want. BTW: the questions *don't have* to be in a certain format, but by picking a certain dialect (or implementation) you will only get answers from people who are willing to use that particular dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Note, the following query is written for Oracle and assumes that a LinkedMerchant only has 1 MasterMerchant. You can play around with the code [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aadd0/24). Also note that I have included more test data than you provided in order to test some additional cases.

```
SELECT MERCHANTID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTCODE
FROM (
  SELECT 0
  , WMP.MERCHANTID
  , WMP.WAREHOUSEID
  , WMP.PRODUCTCODE
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ML.MASTERMERCHANTID, WMP.PRODUCTCODE ORDER BY ML.PREFERENCEORDER ASC NULLS LAST) MERCH_RANK
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY WMP.MERCHANTID, WMP.PRODUCTCODE ORDER BY WM.PREFERENCEORDER ASC NULLS LAST) WARE_RANK
  FROM MW_WAREHOUSEMERCHANTPRODUCT WMP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MW_WAREHOUSEMERCHANT WM ON 0=0
                AND WMP.MERCHANTID  = WM.MERCHANTID
                AND WMP.WAREHOUSEID = WM.WAREHOUSEID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MW_MERCHANTLINK ML ON 0=0
                AND WMP.MERCHANTID = ML.LINKEDMERCHANTID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MW_WAREHOUSEMERCHANTPRODUCT MASTER ON 0=0
                AND ML.MASTERMERCHANTID = MASTER.MERCHANTID
                AND WMP.PRODUCTCODE     = MASTER.PRODUCTCODE
  WHERE 0=0
    AND WMP.STOCKLEVEL > 0
    AND NVL(MASTER.STOCKLEVEL, 0) <= 0
)
WHERE 0=0
  AND MERCH_RANK = 1
  AND WARE_RANK  = 1
;
```